# Inconsistency in GHCi between representations of values of type String and [Char]

Tags: haskell

Take the following definitions:

```hs
p = "abc"
q = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Because strings are lists of characters, the expression `p == q` will evaluate to `True`. That's just fine.

When I let GHCi evaluate expression `p`, it shows value `"abc"`. That is expected, since `p` is of type `String`. (In GHCi, the command `:type p` shows `p :: String`.) But when I let GHCi evaluate expression `q`, it also shows value `"abc"`. That is actually unexpected, since `q` is of type `[Char]`, not `String`. (In GHCi, the command `:type q` shows `q :: [Char]`, not `q :: String`.) So despite the type equality of `String` and `[Char]`, I would expect `q` to be shown as a list of characters, not as a string of characters.

As I see it, the expression `['a', 'b', 'c'] :: String` should produce the string value `"abc"`, while the expression `"abc" :: [Char]` should produce the list value `['a', 'b', 'c']`. But it doesn't seem to work that way. I consider that to be strange. So how can I actually show both `p` and `q` as a list of characters (`['a', 'b', 'c']`) instead of as a string of characters (`"abc"`)? And if that is not possible, why is that not possible? (If a string **is** a list of characters, shouldn't I be able to **show** it as a list of characters as well?)

Comment: The types `[Char]` and `String` are exactly the same. If they were different, `p == q` would raise a type error. GHCi tries to print types using the same notation as the one used in the source code to help the programmer, but the types are still the same. The `Show` typeclass contains a "trick" so to make `[Char]` use a different output than other lists, as you discovered.

Comment: There's even a third way it *could* print the value: `'a':'b':'c':[]`; both `['a', 'b', 'c']` and `"abc"` are syntactic sugar for defining values of this type. The *syntax* used is not part of the value itself, and the `Show` instance is being quite *consistent* in always using the string-literal form.

Comment: In Haskell, we take equality seriously. When we write `type String = [Char]`, we *really mean* those two types are equal -- there are no observations you can make inside the language that distinguish them. (Of course, as usual, the metatheory, i.e. ghci, can do things the theory itself cannot.) As a corollary, because `show` is implemented in the language, it *cannot* distinguish (and cannot allow you to distinguish) between the two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`String` and `[Char]` are exactly the same type. The `Show` typeclass contains a "trick" to print that type using a different syntax than other lists.

If you need the regular list-like output, you could use a custom `Char`-like type to bypass that exception. Note that you will need a conversion to that type before printing the result.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import Data.Coerce

newtype C = C Char

instance Show C where
   show (C c) = show c

main :: IO ()
main = do 
   print $ map C ['a', 'b', 'c']
      -- output: ['a', 'b', 'c']
   print $ coerce @[Char] @[C] ['a', 'b', 'c']
      -- output: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

The `map C` way is simpler but less efficient. The `coerce` way uses safe coercions to make a zero-cost conversion from `[Char]` to `[C]`.

Comment: Since you actually managed to create a workaround for the `Show` typeclass to represent a list of characters as an actual list of characters, I marked your answer as the accepted one. So if the desire would arise, I now know how I could do it. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Hmm, it strikes me that the `map C` way really _shouldn't_ be less efficient.  I would have thought that the `print` would do some sort of map/fold, then fusion would cause the two maps to join, and finally the newtype constructor would be eliminated.  However, it seems `show` for `[a]` doesn't use a fold, so perhaps no fusion?  Huh!

Comment: @DDub I am not terribly familiar with the fusion-based optimizations. In principle, `map C` could indeed be optimized away as you mentioned. Again in principle, I think it could even be translated to `coerce` even in non-fusion contexts.

Comment: Wouldn’t an easier solution be to make a custom print function that prints the characters separately?

Comment: @scatter Possibly, yes. However, the above might generalize to some more complex types such as lists-of-lists-of-Char, or trees-of-...-of-lists-of-Char. By using a custom `Show` instance, we can reuse the already-existing machinery to print trees, etc.

Answer (score 4):

> So how can I actually show both p and q as a list of characters (`['a', 'b', 'c']`) instead of as a string of characters (`"abc"`)?

You can’t. `:type` has the ability to make the distinction because it’s part of GHCi, but `Show` (what determines how the value is presented) is a typeclass. The type alias `String` can’t have a different implementation of `Show` from `[Char]`.

Comment: I understand. And since we generally don't want strings to be shown in list-style syntax, we just have to accept that lists of characters will be shown as strings, right? Since that syntax is also a lot more compact, I think I can learn to live with that. ;)

Answer (score 3):

`String` is merely a type alias for `[Char]`; they are **exactly** the same type.

In fact, `"abc"` is just syntactic sugar for `['a', 'b', 'c']`<sup>1</sup>. Both `p` and `q` are exactly the same as data structures in memory. It isn't possible for any Haskell function to be passed these values and tell which one was defined with double-quote syntax and which with square-bracket syntax. So it isn't possible for `show p` to be different from `show q`.

What perhaps should be more surprising is that GHCi prints different things in response to `:type p` and `:type q`. `String` and `[Char]` are the same type, so how can they be displayed differently?

However, displaying the types of things is not really a Haskell language feature; at runtime functions can only inspect the *values* of their arguments, not their types. Printing of types only happens "outside" the Haskell language proper: in error messages from the compiler, and in diagnostic messages in the interpreter like `:type` (if it were possible for `:type` to be an ordinary Haskell function it would be, and there wouldn't be a special interpreter command starting with a colon). So GHC (and GHCi) goes to some lengths to remember which way equivalent types were written by the user, and use the same (or similar) way of writing types in its output messages. This is purely an attempt to provide more helpful output; it isn't saying there is anything **different** about the two types, it's just trying to speak to you using the same terminology you used to speak to it.

For example, you can see this happening almost exactly the same way with a custom type alias you define:

```
Prelude> type Foo = Int
Prelude> x = 1 :: Int
Prelude> x
1
Prelude> :t x
x :: Foo
Prelude> y = 1 :: Int
Prelude> y
1
Prelude> :t y
y :: Int
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually suare-bracket syntax for lists is *also* just syntactic sugar for the use of the data constructors of the list ADT: namely `:` and `[]`. So both `"abc"` and `['a', 'b', 'c']` are just alternate ways of writing the same runtime value: `'a' : 'b' : 'c' : []`

Comment: Thanks for this answer. As a Haskell newbie, I am still getting used to the language and the tools. This explanation makes a lot of sense to me.